# Notational ambiguity in "$\sqrt 2$ = a rational number"

Tags: notation

I was reading chapter 29 page 296 of the book [*A Book Of Abstract Algebra*](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Book_of_Abstract_Algebra.html?id=qviuEUavE4IC) (second edition) written by Charles C. Pinter, and the equation below was given: $$\sqrt{3} = a + b\sqrt{2}$$ where $a, b \in \mathbb {Q}$.

They were solving for $\sqrt{2} $ in terms of $a$ and $b$.
The instruction given was to square both sides and solve for $\sqrt{2}$
What I did was 
$$\big( \sqrt{3} \ \big)^2 = \big(a + b\sqrt{2}\ \big )^2 \implies 3 = a^2 + 2b^2 + 2ab\sqrt{2}.$$
Looking at this, I don't find anyway to get to their final answer of $\sqrt{2} = a$ when solving for $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: What's the question?  If all you want to do is to find some solution to the initial equation, take $a=\sqrt 3$, $b=0$.  You must have conditions on $a,b$, no?  If, say, you required that $a,b\in \mathbb Q$ then there are no solutions.  So...what did you mean?

Comment: Can you please check the page/chapter? In my book, page 296 relates the chapter 31. Where is the equation precisely?

Comment: @user376343, I found the excerpt in my answer in the second edition. I googled to it online at https://books.google.com/books?id=ZAo_AwAAQBAJ&q=296#v=snippet&q=296&f=false

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting from page 296 of Pinter:

> Observe that $\sqrt3$ cannot be in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$; for if it
>   were, we would have $\sqrt3=a+b\sqrt2$ for rational $a$ and $b$;
>   squaring both sides and solving for $\sqrt2$ would give us $\sqrt2=$ a
>   rational number, which is impossible.

Note, the "a" in "$\sqrt2=$ a rational number" is the *article* a, not the variable $a$, i.e., "the square root of $2$ would be a rational number."

Comment: Good catch!  $\quad$

Comment: @BarryCipra Thanks for the clarification

Comment: For disambiguation, it might have been better to write something like $\sqrt{2} = (\text{a rational number})$, or "...would imply that $\sqrt{2}$ is equal to a rational number".  It may also be worth noting the subtle fact that the article "a" is not italicized, so it is not a variable (though this is, frankly, quite subtle).